# How to configure WAMP for codeingiter?

Tags: apache, codeigniter, wamp

I have been using Codeigniter,suddenly i am facing a strange problem. I downloaded CI-2.2.6 and put it under my WAMP root.So For my project i linked all the CSS and JS in a page_head file using **SITE_URL** function. But somehow it didn't work when i open the page source i get this link

```
 <link href="http://::1/portal/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

which instead should be:

```
 <link href="http://localhost/portal/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When i type in 127.0.0.1 and then my project its works perfectly fine. 
How do i make same things possible for localhost/projectname

A friend of mine told me that it was IPV6 error/issue. So what changes should i do to make my site_url as localhost/projectname instead of https://::1/project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the url helper feature

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Or you can autoload it in application > config > autoload.php

Then you can use

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/jquery-ui.css');?>
```

Use site url on controllers and base url on views I find works better.

On View

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/jquery-ui.css');?>">
```

Directory Layout

```
application

assets > css

assets > js

assets > images

system

.htaccess

index.php
```

On the application > config > config.php do not leave base url blank

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/portal/';

// If need to remove index.php make blank
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also when you use wamp and need to have a htacess file on main directory make sure you have enabled Apache modules **rewrite module**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: what happens if i keep base_url blank? what is it's purpose./

Comment: Some times there is links not correct I have come across may be different for others. But in codeigniter 3 can not be blank.

Comment: Okay But is there any way i can use stick to site_url function ? I have already activated my rewrite module

Comment: On controllers is good for site_url(). base_url() good for views. But that's my thought.

Comment: Are you sure that `base_url('index.php/assets/css/jquery-ui.css')` would work?

Comment: @Tpojka Some times I have had to use it in the past

Comment: Because it is not valid file URI. First one - ok, but second one, I have never seen in function. Please, if you can't find valid example for that one, exclude it from answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your wamp server with simple php file. If it is working fine then no issue in wamp configuration issue with your system. Actually, you need to check wamp configuration with your system/computer not with codeingiter

see these guidelines of proper installation and configuration:[Link](https://mythemeshop.com/blog/installing-wamp-server/?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=4acb1566363082d4f5408551b1842e6748175f46-1607068138-0-AU0rHbwyScGxCosYra8HhWG1OCAbmS99ItQCN1crA4wHjKXAjLPRldmXIw2NLb3JhtbDz69MZ9n7xwR81HMe6NFicvpN6EzVAw06Z6lg6qrOVAuk0mj51VhEGbTTE-0CZbhOOSMYvqWHFOJvOA8TO-Z2ldLYnuoWBJ5ISCa9vtzGGQbjbzyWwJNkr90lAZ2MNim-sjKk-_VcZD4y2J2rBgWGDwkDAysOChCxP0MmYbHMrg3z8iLxjfAH6bKiOoHFOTJFm0hbdmKU1MNdgJCriWP9Z8OGb9TulS61Tz2u1_08wgPnCo2u5jm4Yopfy5E1QOYQAHT9fRudZwHExiStHv7RgbDvdHPmybn8ZgOVPEioq-mtXozPNnnJwrR91RqSytCBcX-rUAOmIVGjQmUJRKsMKnXTfbGPf9awdkM9Uy0LTjBKlSczRFHAV-GQ2RoA1P7J8CiQGWVSXkEippdjmouFJEcTtkMAC7etcClxHe0aaVDqekucsHW7UXXyoI-gVsyBGGkS6BCUMpYPwC7LaDstya-EGpQB-513YnTEo3vafcQpujh6g_LjvCkXDDmwdw)